# По глупости были забанены гуглом. Как пересоздать аккаунт?

Tags: google-play, юридические-аспекты

Собственно, в чем вопрос. После нелепой нашей ошибки гугл забанил наш аккаунт разрабов (на нем ранее было 2 блокировки). Если купить новый аккаунт, при условии что мы на него не будем заливать никаких старых проектов, (с тех же компов, телефонов и т.д.) его заблокируют? Если да, что нужно изменить чтобы гугловцы не поняли что это мы?

Comment: что бы гугл не понял, нужно поменять разработчиков (полностью) и место. А также все остальные аккаунты, дейвайсы и менеджеров.